# compare columns in two csv files and extract the matched column in a third csv file

Tags: python, csv

I would like to compare columns in two csv files and extract the matched values as the following:

**file1.csv is**

115.06603,  5.9

114.74721,  5.4

114.85107,  6.2

111.17744,  5.5

192.77787,  3.2

189.70226,   5

0.46762,            3.7

2.21539,            3.5

2.96667,            3.6

**And file2.csv is**

115.06603

115.06603

114.74721

114.74721

114.74721

114.74721

114.85107

114.85107

114.85107

114.85107

114.85107

111.17744

111.17744

**The output file file3.csv should be**

115.06603,      5.9

115.06603,      5.9

114.74721,      5.4

114.74721,      5.4

114.74721,      5.4

114.74721,      5.4

114.85107,      6.2

114.85107,      6.2

114.85107,      6.2

114.85107,      6.2

114.85107,      6.2

111.17744,      5.5

111.17744,      5.5

I used the following code but the output file give only the first column not the two columns. Could you help me in this problem?

```
>>> with open("file1.csv", "rb") as in_file1, open("file2.csv", "rb") as in_file2,    open("file3.csv", "wb") as out_file:
...   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)
...   reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2)
...   writer = csv.writer(out_file)
...   for row2 in reader2:
...     for row1 in reader1:
...       if row2[0] == row1[0]:
...         row2[1] = row1[1]
...     writer.writerow(row2)
```

**Edit**
I used your code but the first part give the following error:

```
data1 = {}
with open("file1.csv", "rb") as in_file1:
...   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)
...   for row1 in reader1:
...     data1[row1[0]] = row1[1]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As the separator in the file1.csv is ; not , I added delimiter=';' as following

```
data1 = {}
with open("file1.csv", "rb") as in_file1:
...   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1, delimiter=';')
...   for row1 in reader1:
...     data1[row1[0]] = row1[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The same error as you see

I added in.file.seek(0) as following

```
data1 = {}
with open("file1.csv", "rb") as in_file1:
...   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)
...   for row1 in reader1:
...     in_file1.seek(0)
...     data1[row1[0]] = row1[1]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the same error. What is the problem? I am so depressed.

**Edit**

the code that I used to remove empty rows

```
with open("file2.csv", "r") as in_file2, open("out.csv", "w") as out_file:
...  reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2)
...  writer = csv.writer(out_file)
...  for row in reader2:
...    if any(field.strip() for field in row):
...      writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: the first block under the edit works fine for me for a comma delimited file with no empty lines. So: 1. Why are you using the "b" mode to read the files, 2. Do you have empty lines in your input files, if so you need to strip them out (or ignore them if row1 has length 0)

Comment: I changed the delimiter in file1.csv from ; to , and it is working. But also this code did not make the match it gave the same as file2.csv. What could be the problem? And Did you use this code before and work?

Comment: If you answer the questions I asked in my last comment I might be able to help you better.

Comment: 1-I omitted b from the code because there is no need to use "b" mode. 2-Yes, I had empty lines in file1.csv but I ignored them.

Comment: Have you tried placing a print statement while iterating over the first file to see what is actually getting stored into data1? And what is your code to ignore empty lines?

Comment: I placed a print statement while iterating over the first file and I get the same as in file1.csv but in different order stored in data1.

Comment: see the edit above for the code I used to ignore empty lines.

Comment: That code is just echoing the row from file2.csv, without adding the data from data1. You will also need to ignore empty lines when you are populating data1.

Comment: I used this code alone separated from the code you send to make the match. And after using this code to remove empty rows I applied the code for match you send.

Answer (score 2):

this line

```
row2[1] = row1[1]
```

won't work, becuase row2[1] does not exist yet.

you should use

```
row2.append(row1[1])
```

instead.

**EDIT**
Also, the inner for loop is also only executed the first time, because the file can only be iteratated over once. You should do something like the following:

```
data1 = {}
with open("file1.csv", "rb") as in_file1:
     reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)
     for row1 in reader1:
         data1[row1[0]] = row1[1]
with open("file2.csv","rb") as in_file2, open("file3.csv","wb") as out_file:
    reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row2 in reader2:
        if row2[0] in data1:
            row2.append(data1[row2[0]])
        writer.writerow(row2)
```

Note that this will essentially load all of file1 into memory. If this is an issue, you can solve the problem of only reading the file once by adding `in_file1.seek(0)` (or something equivelant to rewind the file that plays nice with the csv reader) after iterating through reader1 in  your original code. That method will be slower than what I have provided though.

Comment: I replaced the line row2[1] = row1[1] with row2.push(row1[1]) in the code but also gave the same result the first column only.

Comment: oh, I just realized that you are iterating through the first file for each line of the second file. For this to work you would need to rewind the first file each time in the outer loop. However, it would be more efficient to loop through the first file once, and store the data in a dictionary, with the first column as a key, then loop through the second file and look up the values based on that key.

Comment: I am so sorry but I am new in using python so I could not understand what you said. Could you translate it to code that I can use,please?

Answer (score 0):

Awk will do this really easily for you:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Result:

```
115.06603, 5.9
115.06603, 5.9
114.74721, 5.4
114.74721, 5.4
114.74721, 5.4
114.74721, 5.4
114.85107, 6.2
114.85107, 6.2
114.85107, 6.2
114.85107, 6.2
114.85107, 6.2
111.17744, 5.5
111.17744, 5.5
```

Here is how it works... Firstly, the "-F," says the field separator is a comma. Then, the "FNR==NR" part tells awk to only process the stuff between the first set of curly braces ({}) while looking at the first file (file1.csv). That says, store the entire line ($0) into an array called "a" at the position dictated by the first column of file1.csv. The piece between the second set of curly braces ({}) applies to the processing of file2.csv. It says print the entry from array "a" at the index given by the first column of the current file (file2.csv).

Comment: It gave an error>>> awk -F, 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' file1.csv file2.csv
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    awk -F, 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' file1.csv file2.csv
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have A[] instead of a[].

Comment: Try copying and pasting the command rather than typing it in yourself - it should work fine - it does if I copy it from above and paste it on my machine, which is a Mac and also on Ubuntu.

Comment: I think the problem is file1.csv because the separator is ; not , what should I change in the code?

Comment: awk -F";" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' file1.csv file2.csv

Comment: My machine is linux, Fedora. May be this make difference.

Comment: It should work fine on Fedora. Did you copy and paste my code with Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V, or type it in maybe with an error? You are welcome to Email me your files and I'll try tomorrow morning on my machine.  mark at thesetchells dot com

Comment: I copied and paste Ctrl-C and Ctrld the code with C-V. Thanks a lot for your offer. Actually I need to help me in doing that so I will send the files in your email. I am sorry what is your email?